# Fixing my CSS stylesheet to cope with HD, 2K and 4K (UHD)

Tags: html, css

I am getting a bit confused with CSS style sheets and the correct procedure for coping with HD and UHD monitors.

At the moment my CSS style sheet is using literal pixel values for the widths of various things. Then, when it is so printing, it overrides some of those widths with 100%.

This is the complete CSS for now:

```
    <style type="text/css">
body {
    width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Calibri, "Calibri Light", Arial, SansSerif;
    background: #666666;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tbody tr:hover td {
    color:#000;
    background:#efefef;
}
.page{
    width: 680px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.textChairman {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FF00FF;
    text-align: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.floatTextLeft {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
.floatTextRight {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.textUppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.textDate {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textWeeklyBibleReading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.cellDate {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    border-bottom-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.borderDotCell {
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #FF00FF;
}
.tableOuter {
    border-width: 0px;
    width: 670px;
}
.tableOuter tr td {
    vertical-align: top;
} 
.borderDotDateRow { 
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #28456c;
}
.containerDateWeeklyBibleReading {
    float: left;
    background: #28456c;
}

.borderDot {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.borderDotTheme {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 480px
}
.borderDotTheme2Classes {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 360px;
}
.borderDotTheme3Classes {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 240px;
}
.borderDotClass {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}
.borderDotName {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}
.borderDotTime {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    text-align: right;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 60px;
}
.borderDotSong {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;   
}
.borderDotMeetingNotes {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.borderDotSpecialEvent {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.borderDotSpecialEventLocation {
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.textStyle {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.containerChairman {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #28456c;
    text-align: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.containerDate {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.textSongTitle {
    /* comment this out to show the song title text */
    /* display: none; */
}
.textMethod {
    /* comment this out to display the method text */
    /* display: none; */
}
.textMaterial {
    /* comment this out to display the student material text */
    /* display: none; */
}
.textCongregationBibleStudyMaterial {
    /* comment this out to display the CBS material text */
    /* display: none; */
}
.containerTitle {
    margin-top: 2mm;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
    width: 670px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.containerTitlePageBreak {
    margin-top: 2mm;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
    width: 670px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    page-break-before:always;
}
.textTitleDate {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.containerTFGW {
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.textTFGW {
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #606a70;
    width: 300px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.gapToTwoClasses {
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.containerTFGWcell {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.containerAYFM {
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.containerAYFMcellNoExtraClasses {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.containerAYFMcell {
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.textAYFM {
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 300px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.cellAYFMMainHall {
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.cellAYFMAuxClass1 {
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
}
.cellAYFMAuxClass2 {
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
}

.containerLAC {
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.containerLACcell {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.textLAC {
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #961526;
    width: 300px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.containerMeeting {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0mm;
    margin-bottom: 3mm;
}


/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Prefix "demo" with newline character    **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoNewlinePrefix {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo prefix text                        **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoPrefix {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo description text                   **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoDescription {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo brother text (publisher,           **
 **              householder, interview 3)  **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoBrother {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo "[" and "]" text                   **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoBracket {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo "," text                           **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoComma {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo " - " text                         **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoHyphen {

}

/*------------------------------------------**
 ** Demo " / " text                         **
 **-----------------------------------------*/
.textDemoSlash {
    /*Uncomment to hide the slash character*/
    /*display:none;*/
}

.containerWeekend {
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.containerWeekendHeadingcell {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #8b8378;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.containerWeekendChairmancell {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #8b8378;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align:right;
}
.textWeekend {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.borderWeekend
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
}
.textPTSLabel{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.textPTSValue{
    font-size: 10pt;
}


@media print {

    body, .tableOuter, .page, .containerTitle, .containerMeeting, .containerTFGW, .containerAYFM, .containerLAC, .textTFGW, .textAYFM, .textLAC, .containerWeekend {
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    .page {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    /* 100 / 680 = 0.15 approx. We use this to work out the % values. */
    .borderDotTheme {
        width: 72%;
    }
    
    .borderDotTheme2Classes {
        width: 54%;
    }
    
    .borderDotTheme3Classes {
        width: 36%;
    }
    
    .borderDotClass, .borderDotName {
        width: 18%;
    }
    
    .borderDotTime {
        width: 9%;
    }
    
    .containerMeeting {
        width: 99%;
    }
}    </style>
```

But it doesn't work well if the user monitor is UHD. So I started to play:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
body {
    width: 680px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
body {
    width: 888px;
    background: yellow;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
body {
    width: 1248px;
    background: green;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
body {
    width: 1664px;
    background: red;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 3480px) {
body {
    width: 2262px;
    background: blue;
}
}
```

In FireFox I can use CTRL+SHIFT+M to simulate UHD resolution. It works.

But as you can see from my CSS I am using these literal pixel widths and it has always worked well.

I don't really want to have to constantly do those checks all through out the CSS script to get it to work right.

So what is the right way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: 9/10 website I visit don't make much use of all those extra pixels that come with 4k monitors (personal opinion). As someone who browsers the internet in 4k I can tell you two things. 1- I am used to a lot of empty space! and 2- Start with media queries for small screens - mobile / tablet - and then let the rest be in units relative to the viewport like `vw` and `vh`.

Comment: All I know is that in my application which has a HTML web browser control that if they are using 4K etc that the content is way over on the right, pretty much off screen which is not good. And it is because 680px is so small to the higher space available. It is not a case of using space up. I just need my editor to reflect a page width so it still looks good. Just I need to have different base values.

Comment: I have the same problem please help us